# Printing boolean numpy array without separators

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pretty-print

I would like to print this array:

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=bool)
```

as

```
.8..
8888
....
....
```

without iterating over each element in a double loop. A terse function like this one:

```
def showGrid(g):
  print(np.vectorize(lambda x: '8' if x else '.')(g))
```

but without standard separators:

```
[['.' '8' '.' '.']
 ['8' '8' '8' '8']
 ['.' '.' '.' '.']
 ['.' '.' '.' '.']]
```

I couldn't find a way to make `np.set_printoptions` drop the standard numpy array formatting separators. Is that possible? If not, pointers to any relevant numpy trickery would be appreciated.

Comment: How about `print(*np.where(a, '8', '.').view(f'<U{a.shape[-1]}').flat, sep='\n')`?

Comment: @MechanicPig Very nice, indeed. I will have to consult the manual to find what you did there, but it works. Post it as an answer and I will accept it. :-)

Comment: "without iterating over each element in a double loop" but why? why make this arbitrary constraint?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga To learn something new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use `np.where` to optimize your current code, which is the same and faster than the function wrapped with `np.vectorize`:

```
>>> np.where(a, '8', '.')
array([['.', '8', '.', '.'],
       ['8', '8', '8', '8'],
       ['.', '.', '.', '.'],
       ['.', '.', '.', '.']], dtype='<U1')
```

To concatenate the characters in each line, I prefer to use `ndarray.view`, which will create a view at a very low cost. It treats all characters in each line as a string with a length of 4:

```
>>> np.where(a, '8', '.').view('<U4')
array([['.8..'],
       ['8888'],
       ['....'],
       ['....']], dtype='<U4')
```

Then use `ndarray.ravel()` or `ndarray.flat` to unpack the flat results into the `print` function, with the newline character as the separator:

```
>>> print(*np.where(a, '8', '.').view('<U4').flat, sep='\n')
.8..
8888
....
....
```

Or use `str.join` to get the complete string:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(np.where(a, '8', '.').view('<U4').flat))
.8..
8888
....
....
```

Comment: it's a nice answer ;)

Comment: Thank you explaining the steps you took.